# Creating basic push-style notification app using WPF and WCF?

Tags: wpf, wcf, distributed

I'm an asp.net developer with very little experience in WPF. I'm looking to create a very basic application, one that would be distributed to a couple clients and allow any given client to send a basic message to all of the others running the application.

I'm not exactly sure where to start or what to look for, being that I'm new to the WPF world. Could someone point me in the direction I need? Would it involve MSMQ? I'd like to stay away from polling if possible, but what generally would I need to know to get started? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the classes in the [System.Net.PeerToPeer Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx).

I did some push notification with WPF and WCF in 2006 using the framework classes from .NET 3.0 which were deprecated by System.Net.PeerToPeer in .NET 3.5 / 4.0, but the old system worked well, so I can only assume that the new classes in the framework are even better :-)

We used push notifications for the majority of data that didn't matter if it was missed by a client, but MSMQ for sending important occasional messages that absolutely could not be lost. You don't necessarily need MSMQ though - we were running mission-critical apps which demanded it, so we played it safe.

[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163356.aspx) to read the MSDN Magazine article that was published to introduced the new P2P namespace in 2007.